# Change JSON-RPC RESPONSE

Tags: python, json-rpc, odoo-11

I am using ODOO 11.0
how to return simple JSON object without JSON-RPC additional parameters

Here is my odoo controller code:

```
@http.route('/userappoint/webhook_test/',type='json', auth='public',method=['POST'], csrf=False,website=True)
def webhook_test(self,**kw):

    response = {
        'speech'        : 'hello my name is shubham',
        'displayText'   : 'hello testing',
        'source'        : 'webhook'
    }
    return response
```

And I am getting this result :

```
{
"result": {
             "displayText": "hello testing",
             "source": "webhook",
             "speech": "hello my name is shubham"
          },
"id": "6eaced3e-6b0d-4518-9710-de91eaf16dd9",
"jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

But I need this :

```
{
"speech": "hello my name is shubham",
"displayText": "hello testing",
"source": "webhook" 
}
```

Any help to point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Works on Odoo11. Just edit below portion of the function _json_response defined at odoo/odoo11/odoo/http.py near about line no : 621-630 as below & Restart the odoo service.

```
def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):

    response = {
        'jsonrpc': '2.0',
        'id': self.jsonrequest.get('id')
        }
    if error is not None:
        response['error'] = error
    if result is not None:
        response['result'] = result
```

to new:

```
def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):

    response = {}
    if error is not None:
        response = error
    if result is not None:
        response = result
```

Then, restart the odoo service

Answer (score 1):

Place the following code in any of your controller before you initialize the controller class

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request, Response, JsonRequest
from odoo.tools import date_utils

class JsonRequestNew(JsonRequest):

    def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):

        # response = {
        #    'jsonrpc': '2.0',
        #    'id': self.jsonrequest.get('id')
        #    }
        # if error is not None:
        #    response['error'] = error
        # if result is not None:
        #    response['result'] = result

        responseData = super(JsonRequestNew, self)._json_response(result=result,error=error)

        response = {}
        if error is not None:
            response = error
        if result is not None:
            response = result

        mime = 'application/json'
        body = json.dumps(response, default=date_utils.json_default)

        return Response(
            body, status=error and error.pop('http_status', 200) or 200,
            headers=[('Content-Type', mime), ('Content-Length', len(body))]
        )

class RootNew(http.Root):

    def get_request(self, httprequest):
        
        # deduce type of request

        jsonResponse = super(RootNew, self).get_request(httprequest=httprequest)

        if httprequest.mimetype in ("application/json", "application/json-rpc"):
            return JsonRequestNew(httprequest)
        else:
            return jsonResponse

http.root = RootNew()

class MyController(http.Controller):
```